# How do I show QLPreviewPanel with SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swiftui, appkit, quicklook

Trying to figure out how to work with QuickLook in SwiftUI on both iOS and macOS. I suspect that in far future, there will be some unified SwiftUI QL API, but can’t see it in sight yet, so let’s work with what we have…

How do I present and configure a QLPreviewPanel from my SwiftUI view? So far, I have this:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    let previewPanelThing = PreviewPanelThing()
    var body: some View {
        Button("OSX preview") {
            print("osx preview")
            if let previewPanel = QLPreviewPanel.shared() {
                self.previewPanelThing.updateControllerForPanel(previewPanel)
                previewPanel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self.previewPanelThing)
            }                   
        }
    }
}

class PreviewPanelThing: QLPreviewPanelDataSource {

    func updateControllerForPanel(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel) {
        print("updating controller")
        panel.updateController()
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
        print("number of items")
        return 1
    }

    func previewPanel(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
        print("requesting preview item")
        let fileURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Thinking-of-getting-a-cat", withExtension: "png")!
        return fileURL as QLPreviewItem
    }   
}
```

This isn’t working. I suspect this is because the QLPreviewPanel documentation says: `The preview panel follows the responder chain and adapts to the first responder willing to control it.` My `previewPanelThing` instance isn’t in the UI and responder chain. I’m not sure how the responder chain works in SwiftUI and how to best go about it.

Comment: so three years later we have `.quickLookPreview()` modifier on SwiftUI which works fine on iOS, but on macOS it doesn't dismiss properly and we get warnings like below such as "-[QLPreviewPanel reloadData] called while the panel has no controller - Fix this or this will raise soon.
 See comments in QLPreviewPanel.h for"

I'm guessing no one has a fix for that yet? guessing its Apple's problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is possible approach on using `QLPreviewView` directly to preview PDF files (in this demo stored in main application bundle, but this does not change the common idea)

*Update: added variant with `QLPreviewPanel` on button click*

```
import SwiftUI
import AppKit
import Quartz

func loadPreviewItem(with name: String) -> NSURL {

    let file = name.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file.first!, ofType: file.last!)
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    return url
}

struct MyPreview: NSViewRepresentable {
    var fileName: String

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) -> QLPreviewView {
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.autostarts = true
        preview?.previewItem = loadPreviewItem(with: fileName) as QLPreviewItem
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) {
    }

    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView

}

struct ContentView: View {
    let qlCoordinator = QLCoordinator()

    var body: some View {

        // example.pdf is expected in app bundle resources
        VStack {
            MyPreview(fileName: "example.pdf")
            Divider()
            Button("Show panel") {
                let panel = QLPreviewPanel.shared()
                panel?.center()
                panel?.dataSource = self.qlCoordinator
                panel?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    class QLCoordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewPanelDataSource {
        func previewPanel(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
            return loadPreviewItem(with: "example.pdf") as QLPreviewItem
        }

        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewPanel) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution works very well but I get a lot of messages like these: `-[QLPreviewPanel setDataSource:] called while the panel has no controller - Fix this or this will raise soon.
 See comments in QLPreviewPanel.h for -acceptsPreviewPanelControl:/-beginPreviewPanelControl:/-endPreviewPanelControl:.`. Do you have any idea how to get rid of them?

Comment: @Asperi I'm struggling to see the relationship between `MyPreview(...)` in the SwiftUI view and the `QLPreviewPanel` below it in the `Button` callback. How are those two related?

Comment: @Dominik I think you can ignore those warnings. I always got those in a pure AppKit implementation of QuickLook, so I don't think you need to be too worried.