# How to embedd QuickLook files inside a view macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, quicklook

This is for a macOS app, here's my code for previewing PDF files using Quicklook:

```
import Quicklook
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {


            Button("Open"){
               showOpenPanel()


            }.quickLookPreview($url)

        }
        .padding()
    }
    func showOpenPanel() {
         let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
         openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
         openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
         openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
         openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
         openPanel.runModal()
        url = openPanel.url
     }


}
```

[image]

How do I have the quicklook preview file be shown inside my content view instead of launching itself in a separate window?

Comment: More specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697842/13409955) shows how to embed a `QLPreviewPanel` for previewing arbitrary files with QuickLook in a SwiftUI app.