# How to use NSOpenPanel to select a file for QLPreviewView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, quicklook

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697842/16297405) i can see QuickLook preview of a pdf embedded in my swiftui view.

But it's only to preview the pdf that's stored in the app bundle resource. How do i use NSOpenPanel to choose a file and display it in the QLPreviewView?

```
import SwiftUI
import AppKit
import Quartz

func loadPreviewItem(with name: String) -> NSURL {

    let file = name.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file.first!, ofType: file.last!)
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path ?? "")
    print(url)
    return url
}

struct MyPreview: NSViewRepresentable {
    var fileName: String

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) -> QLPreviewView {
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.autostarts = true
        preview?.previewItem = loadPreviewItem(with: fileName) as QLPreviewItem
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) {
    }

    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView

}

struct ContentView: View {



    var body: some View {

        // example.pdf is expected in app bundle resources
        VStack {
            MyPreview(fileName: "testing.pdf")
            Divider()
        }
        
        Button("Select PDF") {

            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
            openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
            openPanel.runModal()
         
            
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE**

This is what i've tried but nothing happens after i choose a pdf file with the openpanel. The View is blank. I think there's something that i haven't done correctly in the updateNSView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var filename = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        MyPreview(fileName: filename)
        Divider()
    }
    
    Button("Select PDF") {

        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.runModal()
        print(openPanel.url!.lastPathComponent)
        filename = openPanel.url!.lastPathComponent
        //
        
    }
    }
}


struct MyPreview: NSViewRepresentable {
    var fileName: String

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) -> QLPreviewView {
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.autostarts = true
        preview?.previewItem = loadPreviewItem(with: fileName) as QLPreviewItem
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) {
        
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.refreshPreviewItem()
        
    }

    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView

}
```

***UPDATE 2**

My latest attempt using now a model to update the file url after choosing one with the open panel but nothing still happens.

It updates **pdfurl** successfully with the file url but the QLPreviewView doesn't update with the changes in **updateNSView**. I'm using the [refreshItemPreview()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookui/qlpreviewview/1504399-refreshpreviewitem) which should work but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here

```
class PDFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pdfurl = ""
}


struct MyPreview: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var pdfVM = PDFViewModel()

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) -> QLPreviewView {
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.previewItem =  NSURL(string: pdfVM.pdfurl)
    
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
        
        
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>)  {

        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)

        preview?.refreshPreviewItem()


    }
    
    

    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView

}
    
    


struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var pdfVM = PDFViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyPreview()
            Divider()
        }
        
        Button("Select PDF") {
            
               let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
                    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
                    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
                    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
                    openPanel.runModal()
            
            pdfVM.pdfurl = "\(openPanel.url!)"
        
          print("the url is now \(pdfVM.pdfurl)")

            }
  
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the fileName in MyPreview the full path of a file url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacky solution but it works....

I used a looped timer that monitors and sets the preview item url which is also now stored with AppStorage

```
class PDFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("pdfurl") var pdfurl: String = ""
}


struct MyPreview: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var pdfVM = PDFViewModel()
    let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)

  
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) -> QLPreviewView {
        preview?.autostarts = true
   
        preview?.shouldCloseWithWindow = false
        preview?.previewItem =  NSURL(string: pdfVM.pdfurl)
        updatedocument()
    
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
        
        
    }
    
    
    func updatedocument() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
     
            let delay = DispatchTime.now() + 0.3
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay, execute: {
                        preview?.previewItem =  NSURL(string: pdfVM.pdfurl)
                    })
        }
    }
    
     

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) {


       }
    
    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView

}
    
    


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var pdfVM = PDFViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyPreview()
            Divider()
        }


        Button("Select Document") {
            
               let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
                    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf", "jpg","doc","pptx", "png", "xls", "xlsx", "docx", "jpeg", "txt"]
                    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
                    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
                    openPanel.begin { (result) in
                if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
                    if let url = openPanel.url {
                        pdfVM.pdfurl = "\(url)"
                    }
                } else if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.cancel {

                }
                }

            }
        
        
        
  
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quick direct. NSOpenPanel is subclassed from NSSavePanel. You can find want you need there.

```swift
let response = openPanel.runModal()

if response == .OK, let fileURL = openPanel.url {
    // read your file here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, can you check my update? how do i make the QLPreviewView update with the new file because nothing happens with what i tried

Comment: I still didn't know how you can get something with just a file name. I think you should use a file URL or a file's full path. Or how can you make sure you "MyPreview" could know where the file is, just from the file name?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not getting the file correctly - currently, you are only getting the last part of the URL. You should get the full URL if you are not loading from `Bundle.main`.

This function will get you a full `URL` from an item:

```swift
func openPanelURL() -> URL?{
   let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
   openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf"]
   openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
   openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
   openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
   openPanel.runModal()

   return response == .OK ? openPanel.url : nil
}
```

[Source](https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/macos-tutorials/save-and-open-panels-in-swiftui-based-macos-apps/).

Then, you can just pass in your `PreviewItemURL` into the `NSViewRepresentable`, like so:

```swift
struct MyPreview: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView
    var fileName: String

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) -> QLPreviewView {
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.autostarts = true
        preview?.previewItemURL = NSURL(string: filename)!
// WARNING! I am force unwrapping above using the !, this is unsafe for a production app
//As it can cause the app to crash. Instead, optionally unwrap using the ? and ?? operators
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<MyPreview>) {
        
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.refreshPreviewItem()
        
    }
}
```

[Docs for the `NSURL` init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1414650-fileurl)

[Docs for `previewItemURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewitem/1419913-previewitemurl)

**Warning**: I am **force unwrapping** in the code above - this **will crash** if you have a nil or incorrect value. In a production app, I would suggest using *optional unwrapping*. See an article from Hacking With Swift [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/when-should-you-force-unwrap-optionals-in-swift).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, i was able to get the correct file url but the view doesn't update with the pdf after selecting one. Take a look at my updated attempt. Thank you for your effort!